# Differentially correct GPX file

Tags: gps, gpx

Is there any way to differentially correct a GPX file using free or open-source tools? Does a GPX file contain the necessary information for differential correction (I can put the timestamp in it accurate to 1s)?

As an aside, do I need to disable WAAS on my receiver for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you need raw pseudorange and carrier cycle data to perform post processing, which is not usually contained in GPX.

Comment: Good point, I was thinking time was the only think I needed. Thanks!